# Cucumber/Ruby: Different table console output and Jenkins

Tags: ruby, jenkins, cucumber

I'm running a Cucumber test in which I need to verify the order of the rows of a table. The table is similar to the following:

```
| name  | url   |        
| x     | url_x | 
| y     | url_y | 
| z     | url_z |
```

When the test raise a Cucumber::Ast::Table::Different exception, I see the differences in my local console output (with colors pointing out the differences).

However, when I set the test in a Jenkins job, the console output of the job doesn't print the table with the differences. Is there a way I can print it out as a Jenkins job result? How is the output with the differences printed out in the local console? Is there a variable where the output is located?

I know I have the exception, but I can't seem to find a method to get the output.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add these arguments when you're calling cucumber:  `-f pretty --expand`. It will print more details to the output.
I am not sure if that's exactly what you need though.